# Laravel 4.1 Eager Loading working, but queries still executed in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eager-loading

I have a straightforward "Projects" model. A project can have many tasks, and each task belongs to an employee. 
I have a page that shows +- 100 projects, and all of the associated (unique) employees. This resulted in 500+ queries being executed, so page loads times skyrocketed to an unacceptable level. So I gave eager loading a try:

```
$projects->with(array('tasks' => function($query)
{
    $query->select('project_id', 'employee_id')->distinct()->get();
}));
```

As far as I can tell through debugging, this gives me the result I want. For each project, the tasks are retrieved correctly, with no duplicate employees.

However. When I try to load the tasks in the view, Laravel is still executing 400+ queries to retrieve tasks for each project.

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
   @foreach($project->tasks as $task)
       @if($task->employee_id != 0 )
           <img src="{{UserHelper::getGravatarUrl($task->employee->id)}}" alt="{{{ $task->employee->name }}}"
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I have tried using `tasks()` and `tasks()->get()` instead, but to no avail. How do I access the eager loaded attributes? 
I prefer not to use dirty raw queries, as Eloquent should be up to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to add a bit to WereWolf's answer:

1) The proper way to get your objects is:

```
$projects->with(array('tasks' => function($query)
{
    $query->select('project_id', 'employee_id')->distinct();
}))->get();
```

the get is OUTSIDE, not inside for Eager Loading.

2) your function task (within projects) should have a one to MANY relationship that points to a Task Model with a foreign key as mentioned by WereWolf

3) Eager Loading enables you to load the N+1 ahead of time for One to One for example if you need to reference the Employee inside projects so can see which tasks goes to which employee instead of running a

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = ?
```

on each `$task->employee()->name` that you run in order to fetch data from the relationship

So eager loading would `SELECT * FROM employee` first - then within tasks would eager load with a WHERE IN (?,?,?) (please correct me if I'm wrong)

4) Brings me to my 4th point would be to eager load employee which will reduce the queries. Make a function relationship of one-to-many inside tasks.

Comment: As it turns out, the eager loading was working as expected, even with the get()inside the anonymous function. It was the UserHelper that was retrieving the user many times. Your explanation is excellent though, eager loading works exactly that way.

Comment: @Maarten00 coming from a non-eager loading framework and pure SQL join etc - i know how it felt :)

Answer (score 2):

According to that, your relationship should be built using `id` field of the `projects` table and `project_id` field of the `tasks` table. Also make sure you have called the `get()` method at the end.

You may use a select in eager loading but make sure you have selected the relation builder keys, for example, if your `Project` has many `Task` and you `tasks` table contains the `project_id` as `foreign key` then you need to select that foreign key in the `select`. So make sure that, `project_id` is available in the `tasks` table as `foreign key` to build the relationship with `projects` table. For example, check this:

```
$r = Role::with(['users' => function($q) {
    $q->select('role_id', 'username');
}])->get();
```

I have `users` table that contains `role_id` as foreign key to build relationship between `roles` and `users` table and has a `one-to-many` relationship declared in the `Role` model so I can use `select()` to eager load related `User` models (only `role_id` and 'username' will be loaded in the related `User` model) but without the `role_id` in the `select` I can't load the related `User` models.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on `select()` working for eager loading as Eloquent potentially needs all the model's attributes to correctly eager load. Either get rid of the select or try adding more columns to the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, I will add my own query which works perfectly to eager load all tasks for each project, as well as the employee and the profiles for the employee.

```
$projects->with(array('tasks' => function($query)
{ 
   $query->groupBy('project_id', 'employee_id')->with(array('employee.profiles'));
}));
```

I am accessing these like this in my view:

```
@foreach($projects as $project)    
    @foreach($project->tasks as $task)
        @if($task->employee_id != 0 )
            <img src="{{UserHelper::getGravatarUrl($task->employee)}}" alt="{{{ $task->employee->name }}}">
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This works great, and has reduced my amount of queries greatly.